# What is the best regex which can split list of http headers?

Tags: java, regex, http, http-headers

My header list format is string of:

```
"headerName1:value1,headerName2:value2,headerName3:value3,..."
```

So since a comma can be present in headers, splitting using it might be a problem.

So what would be the characters that might not be present within the headers which I can use for splitting?
This is my code:

```
public List<Header> getHeaders(String headers) {
List<Header> headersList = new ArrayList<>();
if (!"".equals(headers)) {
String[] spam = headers.split(",");
for (String aSpam : spam) {
    String[] header = aSpam.split(":",2);
    if (header.length > 1) {
        headersList.add(new Header(header[0], header[1]));
    } else {
        throw new HTTPSinkAdaptorRuntimeException("Invalid format");
    }
}
return headersList;
}
```

My desired output is an array, `{"headerName1:value1", "headerName2:value2", "headerName3:value3", ...}`
The problem is: "From: Donna Doe, chief bottle washer ,TO: John Doe, chief bottle washer "
scenario like this it does not work well.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What is the problem   with your approach?

Comment: I tried with commas but headers also contain commas and then return invalid array.

Comment: Please show your code for us to have a clearer understanding of what the problem you are dealing with looks like.

Comment: public List<Header> getHeaders(String headers) {
        List<Header> headersList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!"".equals(headers)) {
            String[] spam = headers.split(",");
            for (String aSpam : spam) {
                String[] header = aSpam.split(":",2);
                if (header.length > 1) {
                    headersList.add(new Header(header[0], header[1]));

Comment: Put it into the question and add a note why it does not work for you. It also looks like Java, please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done.

Comment: Do you mean you are using `javax.mail.Header` class? Check [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/tGSom3), let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: Please check http://ideone.com/tGSom3 and let know if it works as expected.

Comment: *So since a comma can be present in headers, splitting using it might be a problem.* If a comma can be present in both the header name and value, you don't have a problem, you have an impossible requirement. How could you parse `a:b,c,d:e`?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to extract any 1+ word chars before `:` as *key* and then any number of any chars before the end of string or the first sequence of 1+ word chars followed with `:`.

You may consider using

```
(\w+):([^,]*(?:,(?!\s*\w+:)[^,]*)*)
```

which is an unrolled variant of `(\w+):(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)` regex. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ys6pRW/2).

**Details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (key)
- `:` - a colon
- `([^,]*(?:,(?!\s*\w+:)[^,]*)*)` - Group 2 (value):

  - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`
  - `(?:,(?!\s*\w+:)[^,]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `,(?!\s*\w+:)`  - comma not followed with 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ word chars  + `:`
    - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`

The `(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)` is more readable, but less efficient. It captures into Group 2 any 0+ chars other than line break chars (with `(.*?)`), but as few as possible (due to `*?`) up to the first occurrence of end of string (`$`) or 0+ whitespaces + 1 or more word chars + `:` (with the `(?=\s*\w+:|$)` positive lookahead).

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/tGSom3):

```
Map<String,String> hash = new HashMap<>();
String s = "headerName1:va,lu,e1, headerName2:v,a,lue2,headerName3:valu,,e3,hn:dddd, ddd:val";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):([^,]*(?:,(?!\\s*\\w+:)[^,]*)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    hash.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)); 
} 
System.out.println(hash);
// => {headerName1=va,lu,e1, ddd=val, headerName2=v,a,lue2, hn=dddd, headerName3=valu,,e3}
```